# Using Ghost's post loop on other pages

Tags: ghost-blog

I use Ghost and on the index page I have the post loop spitting out post excerpts.

Now I would like to make another page that lists only the titles of the posts.

However I do not have the post loop available on other pages.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

This is currently (Ghost v0.5.3) not possible to do. It will however be something you can expect to do with the `query` helper once it's shipped (see the [Ghost Roadmap](https://trello.com/c/wTfXNqRX/49-themes-query-helper) for reference).

Some themes have implemented what you are asking for by using client-side JavaScript and fetching post titles from the RSS feed (which can be paginated). The RSS feed lives at `/rss` and can be paginated by adding the page number to the URL: `/rss/2`, `/rss/3` etc.

Comment: could you point me to some of these themes? or show me how to modify them?

Answer (score 1):

hi this is not exact the same thing you looking for https://github.com/danecando/jquery.ghostrelated but you can check the source how you can paginate between the rss 1/2... and grab the posts

Comment: it seems like i can use this only inside of post.hbs? how can i use it on another page?

Comment: hi create a DIV like <div class="custom-post"></div> and put in a static page now you can append( http://api.jquery.com/append/ )  things over JS to this DIV but this is very hacky beter wait for the API